# prevent ajax call from firing repeatedly

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(event){
$.ajax({
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var response = json[i];
         $('.result_new').append('<p>' + response.name + '</p>');
    }
        //$('.content').append('<p>' + response.total + '</p>');

        }
    });
```

})

event.stopPropagation()

isn't preventing the ajax call from being called repeatedly. Is there a function for this in Jquery?

Comment: I don't see anything calling this repeatedly. Are you saying the click event is being triggered repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){
  if( !$(this).hasClass('loading') ) {
    //add control class
    $(this).addClass('loading');
    //do ajax...
    $.ajax({
      success: function() {
        $('.myDiv').removeClass('loading')
      }
    })
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.stopPropagation()` only prevents the event from bubbling up (from .myDiv to it's parent element until reaching the window). It doesn't prevent the function from executing.

You can use various methods to identify whether the request was sent or not, for example set `.data()`, e.g:

```
$(".myDiv").click(function() {
    if (typeof $(this).data('inTheMiddleOfAnAJAXCall') == "undefined") {
        $(this).data('inTheMiddleOfAnAJAXCall', true);
        // Create an AJAX Call
    }
});
```